# Node.js - Read a CSV file and call extenal API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, csv, parsing

I need to read a CSV File (contacts) and insert into a external API, specifying and ID. But I can't access an external variable inside `fs` clousure and I can't save the parser data on users array. Any idea?

const users = [];

```
fs.createReadStream(`${filePath}/${fileName}`)
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', function (row) {
        users.push(row)
    })
    .on('end', function () {
       // Here inside I need to call a API, but I need an external ID to this scope
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're saying "I can't access an external variable inside fs closure". With closures generally you can access variables from the parent scopes, up to the global scope. Could you clarify the context, or provide more code? thanks (Something like this ought to work:

```
const users = [];
const API_ID = 'SECRET';

fs.createReadStream(`${filePath}/${fileName}`)
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', function (row) {
        users.push(row)
    })
    .on('end', function () {
       api.call(users, API_ID);    // both variables defined in parent scope
    });
```

Comment: It's my mistake! my variable was undefined and I was a little confused. Thanks!